Model training/inference with multiple similar models in parallel
Assume I have pre-trained neural network from Huggingface which I execute via transformers.
Now I have several, say, 64, instances and they should all make predictions with that neural network in batches. The problem is that each of these instances has a certain sub model/field we want to use for this instance.
Now the question is, can we train the last layer or perhaps the bias term in such a way for EACH different sub model/field, such that we can process all the requests together in one batch, despite each instance gets the content particularly suited to his scientific field.
So it should not be that we have separate neural networks for each scientific field and we do batch jobs there.
Instead it should be one big batch, but at the very end of each token generation process there are the deviations for each scientific model/field.
Is that possible? It would be great if you could help us here.

There are several options to achieve that and it depends a bit on your data. One option would be to train one model on all data where each sequence has a subfield-specific special token. Another one would be adding several heads, maybe with ModuleDict. However, your question is too broad for SO. Voting to close. Feel free to reach out via linkedin.
